# App crashes in background while changing permission - swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I need to prompt users to change camera permissions for my app via a UIAlertController. The alert has the following action:

```
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Open Settings", style: .default, handler: { (action) -> Void in

    guard let settingsUrl = URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString) else {
        return
    }

    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(settingsUrl) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(settingsUrl)
        })
    }
}))
```

This does work in so far as it opens the settings, but if the user changes the Camera permission, the app crashes in the background with `Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 9`.

They can now open up the app and the permission is correct, but they need to start from the beginning. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: is this occurs in device ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26115265/app-crashes-on-enabling-camera-access-from-settings-ios-8

Comment: @KKRocks This is on an actual device, yes.

Comment: @ThatlazyiOSGuy웃 The top reply in that link makes it seem like this is the intended behavior. Do you know if that is true?

Comment: @James Yes...it is the default behaviour.If you want to restore your app state follow the answer

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Your app is not crashing its just forced to restart by iOS with new privacy settings. So when you change the camera permission then it means privacy policy changed, so app will be killed if its attached to debugger else it will relaunch.

Also, Not only camera permission If the user at some point changes the Address Book, Calendars, Reminders, Camera, or Photos permissions, iOS will SIGKILL the app. (it's default behaviour of iOS)

Comment: This seems to be it. Thanks for the info.

Comment: I just added exit(0) when i opened the camera settings. It's working fine

Comment: When using a side-load attached to Xcode system:

1- app does restart
2- signal 9 is logged in debugger
3- Xcode is disconnected (I assume, the device restarts the process)

Comment: @Jaydeep, do you have an "official" doc link where this behavior is explained ? thanks :) !

Comment: @PaulAigueperse, Yes its available in official site. Please look at page number 24 https://download.developer.apple.com/wwdc_2012/wwdc_2012_session_pdfs/session_710__privacy_support_in_ios_and_os_x.pdf