# App is forced to restart by iOS with new privacy settings

Tags: ios, swift, camera, settings

if the user changes the Camera permission, the app crashes in the background with Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 9 .

They can now open up the app and the permission is correct, but they need to start from the beginning. Does anyone know how to fix this?

I need to prompt users to change camera permissions for my app via a UIAlertController. The alert has the following action:

```
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Open Settings", style: .default, handler: { (action) -> Void in

    guard let settingsUrl = URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString) else {
        return
    }

    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(settingsUrl) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(settingsUrl)
        })
    }
}))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [App crashes in background while changing permission - swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43974752/app-crashes-in-background-while-changing-permission-swift)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is not a problem of your application. Its just the way apple designed iOS. iOS will terminate the application when user change certain permissions of it.

Actually you will get a SIGKILL message but no Crash log when toggling settings. In this situation even `applicationWillTerminate` not get called!

So the answer is you can't fix it.

Look at page 24 of [this slide](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2012/wwdc_2012_session_pdfs/session_710__privacy_support_in_ios_and_os_x.pdf)

Comment: Is there any statement by Apple where does it conclude for same?

Comment: Yes. Look at page 24. http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2012/wwdc_2012_session_pdfs/session_710__privacy_support_in_ios_and_os_x.pdf

Comment: Thanks sepehr.

Data Isolation:
• If permissions changes, app is quit
■ Background task expiration handler is called, if registered
■ iOS then kills the application

Answer (score 1):

According to Apple privacy policies after iOS 6 for Data Isolation:

- Builds on top of the sandbox
- User permission gathered by iOS
- Access to data is disallowed without user permission
- If permissions changes, app is quit
- Background task expiration handler is called, if registered
- iOS then kills the application