# Watch App get killed while allowing/disallowing camera permission on iPhone App

Tags: ios, swift, permissions, watchkit, watchos

I developed an iOS app along with the Watch OS app.
We are using an iPhone camera for capturing video.
To capture video iPhone app needs permission from the app user.
When iPhone displays a permission dialog and the user allows/disallows permission respective Watch App gets killed with debugger signal 9.
If I remove camera permission then the Watch app works fine.

Comment: i think you need to handle camera permission while asking for permission...checking if user has allowed/denied/partly allowed the camera usage permission.!!....If it is the case i can put the extension code in answer if you say..! [voted Up]

Comment: @teja_D I hope you are clear now.

Comment: @AbishekThangaraj Yes, I am. Still, users are thinking the app is crashing : |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app is not crashing its just forced to restart by WatchOS with new privacy settings. So when you change the any permission in iPhone then it means privacy policy changed, so app will be killed if its attached to debugger else it will relaunch. its happing on both Apple Watch and iPhone. if you change the permission in Apple Watch iOS app will restart. if you change the permission in iOS app Apple Watch app will be restart.

Also, Not only camera permission If the user at some point changes the Address Book, Calendars, Reminders, Camera, or Photos permissions, WatchOS app will SIGKILL the app when change App permission in iPhone. (it's default behaviour of iOS and WatchOS)

Please refer the below links

[App killed by SIGKILL when changing privacy settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652502/app-killed-by-sigkill-when-changing-privacy-settings) ,
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/64740,
[App crashes in background while changing permission - swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43974752/app-crashes-in-background-while-changing-permission-swift),
[App crashed in iOS 6 when user changes Contacts access permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12810638/app-crashed-in-ios-6-when-user-changes-contacts-access-permissions)